# Mysql down on my server (log files)

Tags: mysql

I have server (on DigitalOcean) with LAMP + site with wordpress 3.8.1.
Sometimes my MySQL server down. I try to plug swap, and it helped sometime (fo example when pst publishing) but sometime my site down...

```
140125  8:47:08 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

140125  8:47:08 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
140125  8:47:08 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
140125  8:47:08 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
140125  8:47:08 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
140125  8:47:08 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3.4
140125  8:47:08 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
InnoDB: mmap(135987200 bytes) failed; errno 12
140125  8:47:08 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
140125  8:47:08 InnoDB: Fatal error: cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool
140125  8:47:08 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
140125  8:47:08 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
140125  8:47:08 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
140125  8:47:08 [ERROR] Aborting

140125  8:47:08 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

140125  9:01:37 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
140125  9:01:37 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
140125  9:01:37 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
140125  9:01:37 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
140125  9:01:37 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3.4
140125  9:01:37 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
140125  9:01:37 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
140125  9:01:37 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
InnoDB: The log sequence number in ibdata files does not match
InnoDB: the log sequence number in the ib_logfiles!
140125  9:01:37  InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!
InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite
InnoDB: buffer...
140125  9:01:38  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
140125  9:01:39 InnoDB: 5.5.34 started; log sequence number 2243359
140125  9:01:39 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '127.0.0.1'; port: 3306
140125  9:01:39 [Note]   - '127.0.0.1' resolves to '127.0.0.1';
140125  9:01:39 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '127.0.0.1'.
140125  9:01:39 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
140125  9:01:39 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.34-0ubuntu0.12.04.1'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  (Ubuntu)
140125  9:01:40 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './DataTable/blog_comments' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
140125  9:01:40 [Warning] Checking table:   './DataTable/blog_comments'
140125  9:01:40 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './DataTable/blog_options' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
140125  9:01:40 [Warning] Checking table:   './DataTable/blog_options'
140125  9:01:40 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './DataTable/blog_popularpostsdata' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
140125  9:01:40 [Warning] Checking table:   './DataTable/blog_popularpostsdata'
140125  9:01:40 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './DataTable/blog_popularpostsdatacache' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
140125  9:01:40 [Warning] Checking table:   './DataTable/blog_popularpostsdatacache'
140125  9:01:40 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './DataTable/blog_postmeta' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
140125  9:01:40 [Warning] Checking table:   './DataTable/blog_postmeta'
140125  9:01:40 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './DataTable/blog_posts' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
140125  9:01:40 [Warning] Checking table:   './DataTable/blog_postmeta'
140125  9:01:40 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './DataTable/blog_posts' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
140125  9:01:40 [Warning] Checking table:   './DataTable/blog_posts'
140125  9:01:40 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './DataTable/blog_term_relationships' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
140125  9:01:40 [Warning] Checking table:   './DataTable/blog_term_relationships'
140125  9:01:40 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './DataTable/blog_term_taxonomy' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
140125  9:01:40 [Warning] Checking table:   './DataTable/blog_term_taxonomy'
140125  9:01:40 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './DataTable/blog_terms' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
140125  9:01:40 [Warning] Checking table:   './DataTable/blog_terms'
140125  9:01:40 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './DataTable/blog_usermeta' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
140125  9:01:40 [Warning] Checking table:   './DataTable/blog_usermeta'
```

Answer (score 2):

The Innodb engine requests 128MB RAM and that fails:

```
InnoDB: mmap(135987200 bytes) failed; errno 12
```

Add more ram or swap (swap would work but obviously be much slower) or reduce the innodb buffer allocation until the error does not occure anymore.